# OroCRM DataAudit: how to show properties labels instead of properties names in "Changes history" window?

Tags: symfony, orocrm

As i saw in examples and my custom bundles - there are only changed properties names and values in "Change history" modal window.

It looks terrible when user see "mainAdditionalContract" but not "Additional contract" (taken from the "crm.agreement.additional_contract.label" translation file)

Is there any solution to provide properties labels to dataAudit? Through annotations or any another way?

Comment: I believe it's possible, entity configs can be used to set field label, but you'll have to get it from there, will require template overrides

Comment: @ishakuta, can you provide an example? I have not found what you talking about in standard OroCRM Application (

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that this is still relevant, but for sake of others looking for the answer here's mine:

DataAudit relies heavily on **__toString()** implementation for setting AuditField names.

I believe you should implement **__toString** method in your entities in order for them to be correctly displayed in grid.

Comment: hm, i will try it soon)